# how to modify html using javascript after the page loads

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, web-inspector, web-scripting

I am new to js and learning how to modify  html using js ,i want to modify:

```
<video controls="" controlslist="download" src="//storage.googleapis.com/media-session/caminandes/short.mp4#t=80">&lt;</video>
```

To...

```
<video controls="" controlslist="nodownload" src="//storage.googleapis.com/media-session/caminandes/short.mp4#t=80">&lt; </video>
```

After the page loads, i want to change `controlslist="download"` to `controlslist="nodownload"`

page src:https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/media/controlslist.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `onload` event like below

```
window.onload = function() {

    // select your expected video tag 
    // change attribute controlslist value to expected one 

}
```

Full Code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    // select your expected video tag 
    // change attribute controlslist value to expected one 
    var searchString = "t=80";
    var videos = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
    for (let item of videos) {
        if (item.getAttribute("src").includes(searchString)) {
            item.setAttribute("controlslist", "Anything I want")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: as you can see at src  there are multiple elements so i can't choose src so can you please post the modified code     src::https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/media/controlslist.html

Comment: @elite Thanks for your explanation, Added full code. Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer.